# Find Push Notification ON

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to know the status of "Show notification" under App info of a my app. If user unchecked "Show notification" i want to show the alert message to user. Is possible to get checked or unchecked details of "Show notification"?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no API to get this data (maybe with root you can read some file system).

and there's a very good reason Google did not create any API for it:

The usage of this check box is so users can prevent app abuse/spam from some developers, so if the app developer were able to find the status of this settings, it would try to use ways around it (e.g. with popups).